# Making a x-www-form-urlencoded request with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const { user } = require('./config');
const axios = require('axios');

const Querystring = require('querystring');

let body = Querystring['stringify']({
    email: 'MY EMAIL@email.com',
    password: 'pass'
})

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}

axios['post']('https://minecraftservers.org/login', body, config)
['then'](response => console.log(response))
```

Im trying to login through a website
it doesn't have an api
the headers are correct
if you're wandering how i knew this, i used chrome dev tools
like reverse engineer

```
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

that's the header they used when i tried to login to the site

this is what i get when i logged in through the site and not the code, it works there.
[image]

Comment: can you try the following. 
axios.request ({
    url: '/user',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
     email: 'MY EMAIL@email.com',
    password: 'pass'
    },
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},

    // ... and other options 
})/.then(response=>console.log(response))

Answer (score 34):

You can use `URLSearchParams`

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('firstName', 'paul');
params.append('lastName', 'fred');
axios.post('/user', params);
```

It avoids adding another library.

Answer (score 4):

I guess systax is your problem. Do you have any difficulties other than the syntax?

```
const { user } = require('./config');
const axios = require('axios');

const Querystring = require('querystring');

let body = Querystring['stringify']({
    email: 'MY EMAIL@email.com',
    password: 'pass'
})

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}

axios.post('https://minecraftservers.org/login', body, config)
.then(response => console.log(response))
```

Comment: In case that somebody wants to use this code now. Querystring API is Legacy. Use URLSearchParams().

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
axios.post('https://minecraftservers.org/login', body, config)
.then(response => console.log(response))
```